# Find all lines containing strings with certain letters X amount of times with grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

So I have a text file containing strings of numbers with a word at the end:

```
123456 126 2 12456 1256 4 46 12346 123456 4 56 word
24 245 1234 356 12346 6 3 346 245 5 12346 12356 word
```

I want to find all lines that have at least 8 strings containing either 1 or 6 or both. So the first line would pass because it has 8 strings (seperated by spaces) that contain either 1 or 6 or both. The second one only has 7 strings that contain either 1 or 6 or both.

I tried the follow regex, but it gives a backtracking limit error: `([0-9]*(1|6)[0-9]* .*){8,}`

Comment: do you have a string that 1 or 6 repeated more than once? either 1 or 6 or both repeated like `1112`, `116565`, `6000066`. please [edit] to respond

Comment: Try similar like this `sed -n "s/\([^ ]*[1|6][^ ]*\).*/\1/p"` (It's just for one occurence...)

Comment: @K-att- Note that `[1|6]` matches one of `1`, `|`, or `6`.

Comment: May I ask what you tried your regular expression with? It seems to work with `grep -E`.

Comment: If I understand well, 1 or 6 or both => 1 or 6.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to craft a regular expression, the following iterates over all whitespace-delimited fields, apart from the last field, incremeting a counter if it contains either `1` or `6`.  If the counter's value is 8 or more, the current record is outputted:

```bash
awk '{ count = 0; for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) count += ($i ~ "[16]") }; count >= 8' file
```

The following does the same thing, but stops counting when we know we would want to output the record:

```bash
awk '{ count = 0; for (i = 1; i < NF && count < 8; ++i) count += ($i ~ "[16]") }; count == 8' file
```

As a shorter (unreadable) one-liner (with the counter running *down* from 8):

```bash
awk '{c=8;for(i=1;i<NF&&c;++i)c-=$i~"[16]"}!c' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With perl:

```
$ perl -ane 'print if (grep /[16]/, @F) >= 8' file.txt 
123456 126 2 12456 1256 4 46 12346 123456 4 56 word
```

- `-a` auto-splits each input line into array `@F`.
- `-n` makes perl run similarly to `sed -n` (i.e. loop over each input line, but don't print anything unless explicitly told to).
- `-e` the next arg is the script to execute.
- The perl `grep()` function returns a count of matches, when used in scalar context (while in list context, it returns the list of matches). i.e. it counts the number of matching elements in array `@F`.

  Note that this function is similar to, but **not the same as** the `grep` command-line program.  See `perldoc -f grep` for details.

---

BTW, if you wanted to print the number of matches too, you could do something like this:

```
$ perl -ane '$x = grep /[16]/, @F; if ($x >= 8) {printf "%2i: %s", $x, $_}' /tmp/junk.txt 
 8: 123456 126 2 12456 1256 4 46 12346 123456 4 56 word
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En 's/ ?[0-9]*[16][0-9]* /&/p8' input_file
123456 126 2 12456 1256 4 46 12346 123456 4 56 word
```